# Getting Run-Time Error '-2147221233 (8004010f)', then getting Run-time error '462' The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The following code used to work but has suddenly started producing the above error message. It's designed to take contact details from each email in a folder, then send a new email out. I've run bug checks and yhe line that fails is:
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test")
Here's the code:

```
Sub ListMailsInFolder()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Lines() As String

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst ' folders of your current account
    Set objFolder = 
 objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("Test")
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents
 a = 1
    For Each Item In objFolder.Items
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            Item.Display
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, a).Value = 
 Item.Body
            Item.Close 1
            a = a + 1
            Debug.Print Item.ConversationTopic
        End If
    Next

 For x = 1 To 208
 If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, x) = "" Then
 Exit For
 End If
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  Set Recipients = objOutlookMsg.Recipients
  Set objOutlookRecip = 
 Recipients.Add("<email removed for forum>")
  objOutlookRecip.Type = 1

  objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = 
 "<email removed for forum>"
  objOutlookMsg.Subject = "Fleet Insurance"
  objOutlookMsg.Body = "Testing this macro" & vbCrLf & 
 vbCrLf & "First Name: " & Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(7, x) & vbCrLf & "Last Name: " & Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(10, x) & vbCrLf & "Email Address: " & Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(14, x)
  'Fleet client relationship team in signature
  'Resolve each Recipient's name.
  For Each objOutlookRecip In objOutlookMsg.Recipients
    objOutlookRecip.Resolve
  Next
  objOutlookMsg.Send
  'objOutlookMsg.Display

  Set OutApp = Nothing
  Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Sometimes (not always), the error *message* is more useful than its *number*.

Comment: Also I'd suggest redacting Daniel and Simon's actual email addresses from the post.

Comment: That error message is basically "An object could not be found".  Do you actually have a folder named "Test"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I do have a folder named "Test". It was working before.

Comment: An update: I'm now getting a new error message: Run-time error '462':
The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

As far as I know, nothing has been changed.

Comment: FYI I've flagged the post for a moderator to redact the email addresses out of revision 1, so it'll be just like they were never there to begin with :)

Comment: If the server can't be reached, that would certainly explain the errors...

Comment: That's a good point. It seems to be connected. I'll have a play around.

Comment: Okay, I've restarted my PC and I'm back to the original error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reliably reference the default Inbox:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListMailsInDefaultAccountFolder()

    Dim objNS As Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim defInboxFolder As Folder

    Dim itmCount As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set defInboxFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objFolder = defInboxFolder.Folders("Test")

    itmCount = objFolder.Items.Count

    For i = 1 To itmCount
        Debug.Print objFolder.Items(i).Subject
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error code is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`. Make sure the folder named "Test" exist under Inbox.

Answer (score 0):

The folders you are looking for, are most likely missing (not according to your Outlook, but according to your code). One reason this can happen is if your Inbox changes name, which it can do if you aren't using an English Outlook. Try this:

```
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst
For Each folder In objFolder.Folders
    Debug.Print folder.Name
Next
```

It lists all folders where the Inbox should be. Hopefully you'll find something that you can identify as your Inbox. Replace that name in your code.